# Rotate Command Troubles

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I went to a few other questions like this, regarding the rotate command, but none of them answered my question... I have the command:

```
/execute @e[r=10000] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-2 ~ minecraft:coal_block 0 /tp @p ~ ~ ~ 360 0
```

And it is doing pretty much exactly what I want it to do - rotate a player when they walk 2 blocks above a coal block. HOWEVER, it is not rotating them 360 degrees from their current position, it is rotating them to the direction (which in this case is positive y/south) of the command block with the above command. Is there any way to navigate around this problem?

Thanks

Comment: `~360`​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: You know 360 is a full circle right? so `~360` will be the same as `~`. You'll need to have it set up to repeat x times and rotate them 360/x degrees each time.

Comment: ahha, right :P Would you mind giving me an example for the command? Sorry

Comment: I don't really know you'd have to set up the tp part in a loop somehow, I don't know much about minecraft, so couldn't be more specific than that

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks for the help though! And I already have it in a loop, just the command might have something to do with it. :D

Comment: you mean you have that command in the question running in a loop?

Comment: Yes, meaning that it will do the command every time the loop powers it, which is detecting for player 2 blocks over a coal_block

Comment: so if you change the `360` in your command to `~10` or something it will keep rotating them, not sure how to stop it after 360 times. Hopefully someone else has a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a combination of relative rotational coordinates and a scoreboard objective. The latter is to ensure that players are only rotated once per stepping above a coal block.

---

### Fancy single objective solution

Set up your objective as:

```
/scoreboard objectives add overCoal dummy
```

On a 20Hz. clock, run the following commands to set the score:

```
/execute @a[r=10000] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-2 ~ minecraft:coal_block 0 scoreboard players add @a[c=1] overCoal 3
/scoreboard players remove @a[score_overCoal_min=1] overCoal 2
/scoreboard players set @a[score_overCoal_min=3] overCoal 2
/scoreboard players set @a[score_overCoal=-1] overCoal 0
```

This might look confusing at first, what with adding 3 and subtracting 2, but it does the trick. Basically, every tick the player is above a coal block, his score is incremented by +3-2=+1, but only to a maximum of 2 (3rd command). The moment the player steps off, the score decreases by 2 (thereby avoiding the value of 1), to a minimum of 0 (4th command).

This means that after these 4 commands are run, the score is:

- **0** if the player is not above a coal block.
- **1** if the player has been above a coal block for *exactly* 1 tick.
- **2** if the player was above the coal block for longer.

All that is left is to put a command to rotate the players with a score of exactly 1:

```
/tp @a[score_overCoal=1,score_overCoal_min=1] ~ ~ ~ ~<R> ~
```

where `<R>` is the amount of degrees you want to rotate the player.

---

### Simpler 2 objective solution

If the above solution was too confusing for your taste, a more intuitive way is to use 2 objectives:

```
/scoreboard objectives add overCoal dummy
/scoreboard objectives add overCoalTime dummy
```

On a 20Hz. clock, run the following commands to set the score:

```
/scoreboard players set @a overCoal 0
/execute @a[r=10000] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-2 ~ minecraft:coal_block 0 scoreboard players set @a[c=1] overCoal 1
/scoreboard players set @a[score_overCoal=0] overCoalTime 0
/scoreboard players add @a[score_overCoal_min=1] overCoalTime 1
```

This achieves basically the same as above, but for `overCoalTime` instead.